# triangle inside square

Tags: geometry

I have to find alpha from following picture:

[image]

With law of sines I almost solved it but don't really know how to solve the final equation.

[image]

Maybe I am going to wrong direction and there are easier ways to solve the problem. Can you suggest method of solving the problem or method how to solve my final equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem as follows:

Note that the angle opposite the $50^\circ$ angle is $130-\alpha$ degrees.

Note that the length of the segment next to the $50^\circ$ angle is $x\tan(40^\circ)$ and thus the length of the other segment on this side is $x(1-\tan(40^\circ))$.

Similarly, the segment opposite the $80^\circ$ angle is of length $x(1-\tan(10^\circ))$.

Thus, we have that $\tan(130^\circ-\alpha)=\frac{x(1-\tan(10^\circ))}{x(1-\tan(40^\circ))}$ so $\alpha\approx 51^\circ$.

[image: triangle in square with annotated values]

Comment: It is not clear to me what you're doing here. Note that if OP's calculations are correct, their answer is $\approx 115 ^\circ$, so I'm not sure why OP accepted your answer.

Comment: @CalvinLin I added an image to clarify what I am doing. Curious to see this difference, I do not know where something went wrong...

Comment: @CalvinLin the formula found by OP is _also_ solved by $\alpha\approx51^\circ$, I [checked with wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sin%28130*pi%2F180-atan%28%281-tan%2810*pi%2F180%29%29%2F%281-tan%2840*pi%2F180%29%29%29%29%2Fsin%2810*pi%2F180%2Batan%28%281-tan%2810*pi%2F180%29%29%2F%281-tan%2840*pi%2F180%29%29%29%29+%3D+sin%2850*pi%2F180%29%2Fsin%2880*pi%2F180%29)